# Словари в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

В статье на вики этот вопрос освещён как-то расплывчато. Там написано, что PosgreSQL может хранить перечисления и массивы (aka кортежи и списки). Вопрос в том, можно ли в PostgreSQL хранить ассоциативные массивы aka словари (dictionary) aka карты (map)?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду, когда говорите о хранении ассоциативного массива? Разве таблица, с колонкой для ключа и колонкой для значения не является ассоциативным массивом?

Comment: Я имею ввиду колонку, в которой хранятся словари.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@Montreal](/users/11712/montreal)](/users/11712/montreal), начиная с версии 9.2 вы можете хранить в ячейке JSON-выражение и обращаться к его элементам. Так что ответ на ваш вопрос, скорее утвердительный.

См. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

Кроме того, есть расширение [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/hstore.html), реализующее полноценный key-value тип данных.